# SpringBoot Application : reading URL going into a waiting state and stuck my project

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am using the following api in my project

## GET: Request

## https://myhost.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=ALL

this url is working in browser and also in RESTClient app like PostMen
but when i invok into my project its going into waiting state

i am usnig many api from different server that's working .
but from this server **myhost.com** waiting for response..
i have waited for response more than 30 Minute

i have tried many thing to get the data from the URL but all are faild

Example 1:

```
public void myFunction() {

        String output = "";
        Root data = null;

        try {

            URL url1 = new URL("https://myhost.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=ALL");
            HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            connection1.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection1.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
 
            if (connection1.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println("NSE INIT : Failed : HTTP Error code : " + connection1.getResponseCode());
            } else {

                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(connection1.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = objectMapper.readValue(output, Root.class);
                }
            }
            connection1.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        }
    }
```

Example 2: I have also used WebClient

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public MyService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
    }

    public void fetchDataFromAPI() {

        System.out.println("Get Data ....");
        this.webClient.get()
                .uri("https://myhost.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=ALL")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    // Handle the response here
                    System.out.println("Received response: " + response);
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger? Where is it waiting on?

Comment: Yes ... After the connection1.setRequestProperty

Comment: Firstly, you need to allow follow redirects and secondly,  you need to set the `User-Agent` header else it will remain in hang state with result into connection timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [@Haridarshan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721066/springboot-application-reading-url-going-into-a-waiting-state-and-stuck-my-pro/77722569#comment137019730_77721066), this fixes the problem:

```java
connection1.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","nSense/1.0 (nSense Technologies)");
```